# Dispatching redux action in componentDidMount causing an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Hello I'm new to ReactJS. I've some code that looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {setFullView,setRecords} from '../actions/ActivityActions'

class BrowseAccount extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            records:[]
        }
        this.handleClickRow = this.handleClickRow.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("infiniteloop")
        axios.post("http://localhost:8282/api/account/options", {
            search  : "",
            limit   : 10
        })
        .then(response => {
            var arr     = response.data.records
            var result  = arr.map( record => ({name : record.name,id: record.id}))

            this.props.setRecords(result)
        })
    }
    compoenentWillUnmount(){
        console.log(this.state.records)
    }

    handleClickRow(){
        this.props.setFullView("ViewAccount")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table border="1">
                <tr><td>No.</td><td>ID</td><td>Name</td></tr>
                    {this.props.Activity.records.map((record,i)=><tr><td>{i+1}.</td><td>{record.id}</td><td><a onClick={()=>this.handleClickRow({i})}>{record.name}</a></td></tr>)}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        SelectReducer   :state.SelectReducer,
        BoxReducer      :state.BoxReducer,
        Global          :state.GlobalReducer,
        Activity        :state.ActivityReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setFullView : (path) => {
            dispatch(setFullView(path))
        },
        setRecords  : (data) => {
            dispatch(setRecords(data))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(BrowseAccount)
```

axios post requests runs in infinite loop

onClick in table row doesn't work

but when I using this.setState() instead of using redux it's NOT causing infinite loop

console.log in componentWillUnmount shows nothing

is there any way to make request working normally and I still can store request data using redux ? (but not in infinite loop)

Comment: the `setState` make the Component re-render. But I this the `setRecords` make the Component re-mount. Let put `console` in `componentWillUnmount` to check if It unmounts and re-mount.

Comment: @TamDc the request still run in infinite loop but the console.log(this.props.Activity.records) shows nothing after I put it in ComponentWillMount

Comment: and I can't click anything on rendered elements in this component

Comment: you need to show more of your component structure. ie how this component is connected to redux and/or parent components that are also connected. @TamDc is right about the re-mount which will be caused by parent renders in some way.

Comment: I'm using react lazy to load component dynamically in parent component

Comment: @lecstor I've updated the question

Comment: `compoenentWillUnmount` is not spelt correctly. You haven't included parent code. Are any of the parents up the component chain connected to redux? Should this `this.setRecords(this.state.records)` be `this.setRecords(result)`? why is there a `records` property in `state` at all?

Comment: @lecstor componentWillUnmount shows the data now, yes there's parent component connected to redux too to manage dynamic import React.lazy

Comment: and I forgot to delete this.setRecord Event, sorry. it's simplified now

Comment: The axios request is in the right place. The problem most likely lies on `setRecords`, could you post the code from this action creator?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case another person arrives by googling, here's a working example of React Lazy + Redux: https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/react-redux-webpack-lazy-loading